# Snappy não renderiza imagem no pdf?

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, laravel-blade, relatório

Estou usando Snappy para gerar relatórios, porém ele não está renderizando a imagem que eu carrego no meu html, o que será que pode ser?

Código:

```
Route::get('/report', function(){
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('templates.report');
        return $pdf->stream();
});
```

---

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="1024">
    <tr>
        <td width="100">
            <img src="/img/logo.png" alt=""/>
        </td>
        <td>

            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">
                        <h2>Helpdesk Vicentino's</h2>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No quadrado da esquerda deveria carregar a imagem.
Desde já agradeço a comunidade.

Comment: Já olhou no arquivo de log do Laravel? Lá geralmente mostra os erros ocorridos na aplicação.

Comment: Acabei usando a url da imagem que está no ftp, funcionou =/, porém de diretórios da máquina não rolou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver utilizando o endereço da imagem no ftp. Porém se alguém souber o por que não funcionou com diretório local, por favor me avise =/.

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa passar o caminho absoluto da imagem.

Exemplo: `<img src="http://localhost/sistema/img/logo.png" alt=""/>`

Comment: Na verdade o problema era tentar acessar a imagem em um diretório restrito, mas valeu pela resposta.